# Apex code to trigger email is not sending Email from Einstein bot

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage, invocable-method, einstein-chatbot

I'm calling an apex from Einstein bot to send an Email. The apex code is running fine and its returning success = True but I'm not receiving Email on the recipient side. I have checked access of apex class in bot permission set, Email deliverability is set to "All Emails" but still its the same issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Maybe the issue is not that it is not sending it, but it is not being received. Have you tried different recipients (with different domains in the email addresses) just to make sure?

Comment: check SFDC Email Logs to see if destination mail server received the mail